# Remove # from URL in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I am using Angular JS for my Front End, php is the Service layer.

I am trying to remove the # from my url.

Now : http://localhost/loginwithangular/#/login

I want look like : http://localhost/loginwithangular/login

I tried : $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);but it is not working.

Could you please some one suggest how to make it work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: add this to inside your  `<base href="/" />` inside `<head></head>` tag

Comment: i have already use <base href="/" /> inside <head></head> tag.but still not work properly.

Comment: `http://localhost/loginwithangular` is this you base URL ? i mean your whole website running inside the `http://localhost/loginwithangular` ?

Comment: ohk i will try it

Comment: if yes then try adding this code `<base href="/loginwithangular/index.html" />` or `<base href="/loginwithangular/" />`

Comment: i will use base url like this <base href="http://localhost/loginwithangular/"> but angular js is throw error like this

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%24locationProvider%20is%20not%20defined......like this

Comment: can you please add this `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true,requireBase: false });` pass this arguments

Comment: What is the exact error your are getting when you set <base href="http://localhost/loginwithangular/"> ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
 config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 }]);
```

Comment: i have already use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in my app.js ;but still does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `<base href='/'>` in your index.html
also in your app.js you need to add

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `RewriteBase /` in your

> .htaccess

file. and add `<base href="/">` in your

> index.html

file and also add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to your

> main.js